# Where does the Zw prefix come from?

Tags: windows, winapi

Where does the Windows native API prefix `Zw` come from? Over the years I've read many answers to this question, including:

- No meaning whatsoever, just chosen to avoid conflict ([official MSDN response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff565646.aspx))
- Zero Wing (AYBABTU)
- `ZW` is `MZ` upside-down, perhaps a homage to Mark Zbikowski, the king of Portable Executables.
- "Zero Weight", because of the reduced parameter checking.
- The `Z` stands for (Mark) Zbikowski, the `W` stands for (Bryan) Willman.

Whilst some of these are rather wild speculation, some seem to have some potential. Do we have any seasoned Microsoft pros around that can shed some light on the subject?

Comment: The documentation is right; it means nothing: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/06/03/9687937.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff565646.aspx) states that it means nothing, and was chosen to avoid conflict (emphasis theirs):

> The Windows native system services routines have names that begin with
> the prefixes **Nt** and **Zw**. The **Nt** prefix is an abbreviation of Windows
> **NT**, but the **Zw** prefix has no meaning. **Zw** was selected partly to avoid
> potential naming conflicts with other APIs, and partly to avoid using
> any potentially useful two-letter prefixes that might be needed in the
> future.

Raymond Chen [further supports this in his blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090603-00/?p=18043):

> What does the "Zw" mean?
>
> Answer: Nothing.
>
> The people who chose the letters wanted to pick something that was
> unlikely to collide with anything. Perhaps they had a prior bad
> experience with having chosen a prefix, only to find that somebody
> ahead of them claimed it already?

Comment: This is nothing new... when IBM introduced the mainframe timesharing subsystem TSO in the early 1970s (which is still in use on contemporary z/OS), they prefixed all its subroutines with `IKJ`–why `IKJ`? Because it was a random prefix which it seemed unlikely anybody (whether inside IBM or at a customer) was already using. Different decade, different company, different platform, same logic.